# Checking for numbers in a switch statement

Tags: switch-statement

Is there an easy way to check for digits 0-9 with a switch statement?  I'm writing a program to check for certain characters as well as digits.  Like checking for '\0', 'F' or 'f', and was wondering if there was also a way to check for 0-9 in a similar fashion.  I know I can write a program to return true or false if a character is a digit 0-9, but wasn't sure how to use that with one of the cases in a switch statement.  Like if I had:

```
const int lowerBound = 48;
const int upperBound = 57;

bool isDigit(char *digit)
{
    if (*digit >= lowerBound && *digit <= upperBound) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

how I can go

```
switch (*singleChar) {
    case(???):
}
```

Comment: The isDigit function can be more concise and just as clear if written as: `return (*digit >= lowerBound) && (*digit <= upperBound);`, or better use `std::isdigit(int)` from `<cctype>` or `std::isdigit(char,locale const &)` from `<locale>`

Comment: oh great, did not know there was one.

Comment: And there is also `std::isxdigit` for identifying whether an input is a hex digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably write the switch statement for the particular letters (´f´, ´F´...) and add the condition in the `else` block.

```
switch ( ch ) {
case 'f': // ...
   break;
case 'F': // ...
   break;
default:
   if ( isDigit(ch) ) {
   }
};
```

(Also note that there is a standard `isdigit` function from standard C in header `<cctype>` and another in `<locale>` that takes a locale as parameter and performs checks based on that locale)

Answer (score 4):

```
switch(mychar) {

   case '0':
   case '1':
   case '2':
   ..
   // your code to handle them here
   break; 

   .. other cases
}
```

This is called 'fall-through' - if a case block does not terminate with a break, control flow continues at the next case statement.

Answer (score 2):

Hang on! Why are you defining your own `isDigit` function when there's one already available in the function in the '[ctype.h](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/ctype.h.html)' header file...Consider this:

```
char *s = "01234"; char *p = s;
while(*p){
    switch(*p){
        case 'A' :
            break;
        default:
            if (isdigit(*p)){
                puts("Digit");
                p++;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Must have supa speed. On a serious note: I was reading a few of my system headers this morning and I learned the 'isdigit' implementation had a unelidable branch and a shared library table lookup.

Answer (score 1):

This would probably do it, but to be honest, it's pretty ugly. I'd probably use a different construct (maybe a regex?) unless I knew this was a major hotspot, and even then I'd profile.

```
switch (*singlChar) {
    case '0':
    case '1':
    case '2':
    case '3':
    case '4':
    case '5':
    case '6':
    case '7':
    case '8':
    case '9':
        // do stuff
        break;
    default:
        // do other stuff
}
```

Comment: This is probably the most common/clear way of writing a case statement where multiple cases satisfy the condition.  It would be interesting academically to see what assembly code is produced for this vs. others.

Answer (score 1):

I think GCC supports a non-standard extension where you can do things like this:

```
switch(myChar)
{
case '0'...'2':
    // Your code to handle them here
    break;

.. other cases
}
```

But it is NON-STANDARD and will not compile under Visual Studio for example.

Comment: I cannot find anything about this. What is this called?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
char input = 'a';

switch (input)
{
  case 'a': // do something; break;
  // so on and so forth...
  default: break
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code.

switch (*singleChar) {

```
         case 48 ... 57: return true;

         default: return false;
```

}

Comment: The ellipsis is a non-standard construct. If you're using GCC exclusively and never need to port your code...

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
int isdigit(char input) {
    return (input < '0' || input > '9') ? 0 : 1; 
}

...

if(isdigit(currentChar)) {
    ...
}
else {
    switch(currentChar) {
        case 'a' {
            ...
            break;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```